# zxJDBC - setting oracle driver class path

Tags: python, oracle, jdbc, jython-2.7

I have set the class path but still on running it is showing

zxJDBC.DatabaseError: driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] not found

below are the class path:

```
/Users/aaj.a/Downloads/OJDBC8-Full/ojdbc8.jar:/Users/aaj.a/Downloads/zxJDBC-2.0.1b1/lib/zxJDBC.jar:zxJDBC.jar:
```

connection is done as follows :

```
 from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC

    ip = 'sample-ip'
    port = 1522
    SID = 'ghnb'
    jdbc_url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@%(ip)s:%(port)s:%(SID)s" % locals()
    driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    self.db = zxJDBC.connect(jdbc_url, 'owner', 'password', driver)
```

how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have JDBC driver ojdbc8.jar in the classpath. You can download the JDBC drivers from [OTN](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I have the driver in class path. /Users/aaj.a/Downloads/OJDBC8-Full/ojdbc8.jar:/Users/aaj.a/Downloads/zxJDBC-2.0.1b1/lib/zxJDBC.jar:zxJDBC.jar:

Answer (score 0):

finally got the solution

download the oracle ojdbc driver from Oracle official website.

Install/Add Oracle driver to the local maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=12.1.0.1 -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

'-Dfile=' is the location of ojdbc7.jar file

Add the following dependency in your pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

after this it successfully connected to DB